# Confusing contract of `select`

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm banging my head trying to understand this contract of `select`:

1. > `onSend`, `onReceive`, `onReceiveOrNull`, and `onLock` clauses are atomically cancellable. When select throws `CancellationException` it means that those clauses had not performed their respective operations.
2. > As a side-effect of atomic cancellation, a thread-bound coroutine (to some UI thread, for example) may continue to execute even after it was cancelled from the same thread in the case when this select operation was already resumed on atomically cancellable clause and the continuation was posted for execution to the thread's queue.

This is what makes sense to me, on the example of the `UI` context:

- the `select` expression chooses a clause and posts its code to the UI event queue
- when the code is picked from the queue, the first thing it checks is the `isActive` flag. If it's lowered, the code doesn't run
- this would break atomicity of cancellation: neither you got the `CancellationException` in the `select` clause nor did the code run (cancellation occurred while the clause's callback was waiting in the queue)
- that's why the `isActive` check is skipped and the code runs even though it was cancelled in the meantime

However, that's *not* the guarantee given in (1). It doesn't say "either your handling code runs, or you get a `CancellationException` in the `select` expression". It only says "if you got the exception, it means the code had not run". This guarantee can be achieved without the behavior given in (2), so it's not the side-effect of (1).

It seems that the description of behavior in (2) is correct, but the guarantee it provides is not as described in (1). It is "if you didn't get `CancellationException`, then the handler code will run".

Shouldn't the documentation state the stronger *either-or* guarantee?

Comment: I've assumed that guarantee for "if you didn't get CancellationException, then the handler code will run" is implicit for all select clauses (not just for the one that are atomically cancellable). In fact, the guaranteed is that if the event that the clause is waiting for happens, then the handler code will run, unless there is a cancellation. Anyway, you are welcome to contribute clarification to the docs.

Comment: Isn't (2) the side effect of "if you didn't get CancellationException, then the handler code will run"? So it isn't a side-effect of atomic cancellation?

Comment: I'm still confused with `it means that those clauses had not performed their respective operations.` This is not guaranteed for non-atomic clauses?

Comment: Atomicity of clauses is a side-effect of atomicity of the corresponding operations, so let's talk about them. `Deferred.await` is not atomic and if you got cancellation exception it does not mean deferred was not triggered (it might have been). However, `Channel.receive` is atomic and if you got cancellation exception it is guaranteed that the element was not received (retrieved) from the channel.

Comment: Now I understand. I thought "the clause performing its respective operation" referred to the actions taken by the handler code. So the contract prevents receiving an item without handling it.